# Passing php variable into javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass a php variable into a jquery function parameter, when i added an id to each loop it only return the first one. How to do it right ?

php code :

```
foreach ($record as $key):  ?>
         <tr>
         <td><a href="" onclick="update_amarta(<?php echo $key->SiteID ?>)"> NOT YET</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function update_amarta(id) {
    alert(id);

  };

</script>
```

Comment: how much records in your foreach loop? please post your whole php code

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: If `$key->SiteID` is a string you'll need to wrap the ouptut value in quotes. In that case you should see an error in the console when you attempt to click the element.

Comment: any errors in your browser's console when you run this?

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @highcal please use this PHP code inside inverted comma's. something like that

```
<a href="" onclick="update_amarta('<?php echo $key->SiteID ?>')"> NOT YET</a>
```

Hope this will work for you. Thank You.

Comment: you might want to explain _why_ you think your answer will help (although of course it is based on an assumption about the data type). That would be much better for those reading it.